# Find out the function based on a specific rule (Non-linear function)

Tags: functions

If I had the table of $x$ , $f(x)$ pairs, and this is the rule:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
1 &1 \\
\hline
\hline
x_i & f(x_i) \\
\hline
\hline
2x_i & 1 +f(x_i) \\
\hline
\end{array}

Basically that means that for every $x$ the function value will increment at the $2x$ point.

I'm struggling to find out the exact function, in which i can input the $x$, and it will give me the correct output. :)

I know that the function will look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaYZ0.png).

So far I constructed this table
\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
x & f(x) \\
\hline
\hline
1 &1 \\
\hline
\hline
2 &2 \\
\hline
\hline
3 & k \\
\hline
\hline
4 & 3 \\
\hline
\hline
5 &  \\
\hline
\hline
6 & k+1 \\
\hline
\hline
... & ...\\
\hline
\hline
8 & 4\\
\hline
\hline
... & ...\\
\hline
\hline
12 & k+2\\
\hline
\hline
... & ...\\
\hline
\hline
16 & 5\\
\hline
\hline
... & ...\\
\hline
\end{array}

where $k$ is the number between 2 and 3, obviously.

I tried [interpolating that table in wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Interpolate[%281,1%29,%282,2%29,%284,3%29,%288,4%29,%2816,5%29,%2832,6%29,%2864,7%29]), but it can't work.
I think that there is simple solution to this function. Or is there?

Feel free to edit the question if you think that it can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of phrasing this would be that $f(2x)=1+f(x)$.

Note that $x=0$ can not be in the domain of this function as if it was there $f(2\times0)=1+f(0)\implies0=1$

A function which fits your data is:

$$f(x)=1+\log_2x$$

Edit: How I arrived at this: take the table you have create and instead of looking at how $x$ links to $f(x)$ look for the reverse link. When $f(x)$ increases by one then $x$ doubles.

Hence:

$$2^{f(x)-1}=x$$

(the $-1$ is just there to match the powers up)

Then from this rearrange to get:

$$f(x)-1=\log_2x$$

$$f(x)=1+\log_2x$$

Comment: Tested it, and it works, but I'm struggling to figure out how did you come to this solution.

Comment: Updated with my how I got the answer.